# Excel: "Count column B if Column A contains my preferred word" Using COUNTIF?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here's my data:

```
  | A   | B
--+-----+------
1 | AAA | Pass
2 | AAA | Pass
3 | BBB | Fail
4 | AAA | Pass
```

I want to count the pass labels from column `B` but only where column `A` is `AAA`.

I think the appropriate function for this is `countif` but I can't formulate a good way to get the answer.

My current formula is:

```
=IF($A1="AAA",COUNTIF(B1:B4,"Pass"))
```

I'm trying to get the exact amount of count of passes when I'm looking for `AAA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `=COUNTIFS()` function:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, "AAA", B:B, "Pass")
```

[image]

Comment: Added another AAA-Pass and BBB-Pass just to check, and it seems to work just fine. Suppose I should have expected as such from one named VBA Pete :-)

Comment: Too easy. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You could consider, based on your if() approach:

```
=if(and(A1="AAA",B1="pass"),1,0)
```

And drag it down as far as necessary and sum that column - not tested as I am on a smartphone, but should work...